# Deployer Extension Official Support and Storage Extension

Tags: 2013, content-delivery

It was my understanding that a Deployer Extension was not an officially supported extension point in Tridion and Storage Extension was the supported type which accommodated the same need to perform custom logic upon deployment.  However, I have just checked the 2013 SP1 docs and see that they provide instructions on implementing custom deployer modules: http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-DA883F20-294E-4D96-BBDA-1EBDB1C42DBB

So if both are now supported, how do I decide which to use, i.e. in what sample scenarios do I use one over the other?

Answer (score 7):

Nick the thumb rule is that if you are dealing with Storage of the item or rather Presentations then it makes sense that you should be doing it at the storage layer and hence use of Storage Extension makes more sense. For anything else during the Deployer process use the deployer extension.

Not the main difference: With Storage Extension you are dealing with the Deployer Process with in the same transaction whereas with the Deployer Extension you have two choice - Either you are dealing with the deployer process before the commit or after the commit of the deployer process but not with in the same transaction.

You may want to refer [THIS](http://pankajgaur83.wordpress.com/2013/06/07/unleashing-storage-extension/) blog post and a small section which may give some insight for your query.

BTW, as far as the SDL Support is concerned, the configuration, the extension point and the concept as such is fully supported and you will get all the help setting it up from the support; whatever is not supported is your custom code, setup and configuration

Answer (score 2):

I prefer deployer extensions for integrations with other systems (search engines for instance) because they give you access on the scope of a full publish actions, whereas i prefer storage extensions for integrations that need to interact with the the same database (such as a custom query table with derivate attributes).

Comment: I do not agree with your suggestion for integration of search engine as doing it at the Deployer Extension might not give the much needed control that you may get in Storage Extension, plus it would be more effective to do at the storage level by using storage extension. Yes it may have been done at multiple places but the main reason may be the legacy that is coming behind - as prior to 2011 there is only one option - deployer extension

Comment: You may want to refer this discussion here: http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/688/solr-search-engine-integration-in-asp-net-website-and-tridion-2011-sp1

Comment: Interesting point Pankaj - but why do you think storage extensions give you "much needed control" compared to a deployer extension?

Comment: Consider a scenario where Publishing process is successful but Indexing to SOLR got failed, it will be inconsistency of data at two sources - This you can not control using DE but ofcourse using SE as in SE you have the flexibility to even make the publishing failed in those scenarios

Comment: you can choose to fail the publishing in DE but only if you are running it in Pre-Commit phase; however, in this scenario if you want to index the URLs (resolved through Internal Links) then it will not be possible.

Comment: Sorry Pankaj, but that makes little sense - you always have to commit one item before you commit the other, no matter where you place the code to do so. In general, i prefer my search integrations to be able to re-index incoming urls when they fail - you try explaining to an editor that his critical publish failed because the search server had a temporary issue.

Comment: OfCourse Rogier..depends on what are business requirements - I faced two client where both of them are saying hey I publish something, it is showing successful but it is not visible on the site - For one of them it was 2009 system upgraded to 2011 so Deployer Extension was used to integrate with SOLR and we could not find a straight fwd way deal with this scenario. In second scenario it was Storage Extension and fairly easy to deal with this situation

Comment: By the way what is your thoughts - Why do you use DE instead of SE in this scenario - What is the advantage?

Comment: And I forgot mentioning...SI4T is using Storage Extension :)

Comment: I prefer DE because i can check the entire publishing package and i a not limited to a particular scope. In the search example, I can cross-reference the entire publishing package and minimize the URL's sent. For instance, i can linkresolve the DCPs that also appear attached to a page (i.e., calculate all URL's that need a reindex) and nicely merge the outcome with the URLs inside of the current package.

Comment: Maybe you both prefer what you know. ;) All things you guys mention is possible in both systems. The crucial difference is that SEs happen inside a JPA transaction, whereas DEs are just Tridion's own transport package handlers (and subsequent file parse code), running on the outside scope of the SE layer. I like SEs because they follow the more modern Java conventions and are a bit more maintainable if you do complex stuff, while for DEs, some methods that you have to use have set as deprecated for a while.

Comment: Implementing a storage extension ensures you get notified when a binary is removed from storage. There is no explicit unpublish action for implicitly published binaries, so deployer extensions don't get the needed notification. See this article for a full description: https://sdltridionworld.com/community/2011_extensions/binaryeventtracker.aspx

Comment: Would it be to much to ask for SDL to make a clear statement in the docs why and when to use SE over DE?

Comment: Great discussion folks.  @Raimond, your comment deserves points. Convert it to an answer and you got my vote.